# Can't upgrade packages

Tags: updates, software-center, package-management

I'm truing to upgrade my packages because Ubuntu Software Center doesn't work. It just chashes when I'm trying to execute it. In terminal I wrote:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And here is an answer:

```
E: Malformed line 57 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list(dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

So what should I do to solve this? And why this error occurred?

Comment: If you choose google that error message , you will get 1000+ answers.

Comment: Here is my line:
deb http://archieve.cannonical.com/ parthner
I was trying to change it according to example but nothing changed.

Comment: I have solve my problem just by commenting that string and updating packages.